# Convergence of alternating series involving a squared sine

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to determine whether the following series converges or not:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty((-1)^{n}(\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}))^2 $

I thought to use the Alternating Series Test, but ran in to two problems:

1. After rewriting the series as $\sum_{n=2}^\infty((-1)^{n}(\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}))^2 $ to ensure the sine squared sequence was monotonically decreasing, I had trouble proving that it was actually decreasing. I thought of using a sketch but I don't think that would be rigorous enough.
2. I had a problem showing the sine squared sequence was null - it seems obvious that:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}))^2$         $= (\sin(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi}{n}))^2 $ = $0$

but I am not sure how to justify moving the limit inside the sine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\left((-1)^n\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)\right)^2=\sin^2\left(\frac\pi n\right).$$So, your series is *not* alternating. And, since\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac\pi n\right)}{\frac1{n^2}}&=\pi^2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac\pi n\right)}{\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}}\\&=\pi^2\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)}{\frac\pi n}\right)^2\\&=\pi^2\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)}{\frac\pi n}\right)^2\\&=\pi^2\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2\\&=\pi^2\end{align}and since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges, your series converges too.

Comment: I don't think it's immediately obvious that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\pi^2$. I would add an explanation of that fact.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp It follows immediately from $(\sin u)/u \to 1.$ I think we can assume this.

Comment: Sure, *I* know that, but I think it's at least polite to note that that's why it's true.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp I've done it, although I don't feel sure that it adds much.

Answer (score 0):

2: You can move the limit inside $\sin$ because it is continuous, as is $x \mapsto x^2$.

1: Note that $\frac{\pi}{n}$ is "obviously" decreasing, so it suffices to show that $\sin(x)^2$ is increasing on some interval containing all but finitely many terms of the sequence $\frac{\pi}{n}$.

That being said, if there is no typo, then the alternating series test doesn't actually apply because $(-1)^n$ is getting squared too. To deal with that, you'll want to use a comparison test.